# How to setup the JIT debugger in Delphi 2009?

Tags: delphi, debugging, delphi-2009

On my machine I have Visual Studio 2008,C# Express,Delphi 7 and Delphi 2009 Architect(No updates).

When I usually run Delphi 7,it notifies that the JIT debugger is currently set to another application(Visual studio in my case) and asks me if i'd like to change it to Delphi.

If I press Yes,I can use the debugger in Delphi 7,otherwise I can't use it.

My problem is that in Delphi 2009 the IDE doesn't ask me to do this and even worse - a crash occurs when I open/create a project.

How do I setup the JIT in delphi 2009?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Registering BDS 2006 / Delphi 2006 / C++Builder 2006 / Delphi 2007 / C++Builder 2007 as the JIT Debugger 
http://support.codegear.com/article/36747

You can modify it to work with D2009

(Edit: Codegear.com no longer exists, the new url is:
http://support.embarcadero.com/jp/article/36747)