# How can I disable Delphi as just-in-time debugger?

Tags: delphi, debugging

Delphi 7 is registered as the just-in-time debugger on my system. How can I disable it so that Delphi will not launch if an application error tries to invoke the JIT debugger?

I stopped the Machine Debug Manager Service but this did not do the trick.

Comment: See [this](http://support.embarcadero.com/article/36747), found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881538/how-to-setup-the-jit-debugger-in-delphi-2009).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to delete the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug\Debugger
```

On a 64 bit system delete this key also:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug\Debugger
```