# Delphi install "broke" visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, delphi

Recently I made a terrible mistake, I installed delphi 6 in my laptop, and chose yes when asked that really long question about the debugger... the result my Visual studio doesnt work anymore.

I remember the fix for this was pretty simple, possibly a registry setting change. I can't remember tho.

I tried loads of things to revert this state as I dont need delphi anymore but do need VS and would rather not have to reset all my dev environment again if i dont realy have to.

I tried:
-  restoring to a Restore point (created one before installing Delphi)
- VS in many states (devenv.exe /reset , devenv.exe /setup ...etc)

In my event viewer I can see:

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 10.0.40219.1, time stamp: 0x4d5f2a73
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.239, time stamp: 0x4e181a6d
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00024e38
Faulting process id: 0x1468
Faulting application start time: 0x01cd35b33ad2193d
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 7beb5eac-a1a6-11e1-93cc-00262256e631
```

Cheers

Comment: How about reinstalling .Net 4.0 and install the latest .Net 4.0 fixes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I asume this long question was about the Just In Time Debugger. The JIT debugger will be invoked when an application crashes. The JIT debugger setting is saved in the registry in [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758741/how-can-i-disable-delphi-as-just-in-time-debugger) locations.

I do not believe that this setting is the reason why your Visual Studio crashes. I have had several versions of Delphi and Visual Studio installed on the same machine without problems. And this setting only has affect when an application crashes outside of a debugger.

Comment: yes me too, but I remember each time I chose Yes on that really long message box i would have problems

Comment: Then remove the registry key and find out.

Comment: @Miau, and next time make sure you actually read and understand those really long message boxes before you say yes to them. ;-)

Comment: @KenWhite and Blobby, the question came only once the first time you run delphi and then never again. (PS: you sound really patronizing)

Comment: @Miau, patronizing in what sense? My point was that (especially as a developer) you should take the time to read and understand dialogs that ask you a question before you choose an answer to that question. It doesn't matter if the dialog was displayed once or repeatedly, the advice doesn't change: Don't answer a question without knowing what you're being asked. :)

Comment: Hey Miau, if you ask a question and get some help and then call the person helping you patronizing, ask yourself how that makes you sound, and whether people will want to help you next time if you insult people who try to help you.

Comment: Did not mean to insult I felt insulted tho, so I said something. Also the person commenting is not the person that replied.