# Fix Debugger Error Notice on Opening Delphi 6

Tags: delphi, debugging, delphi-6

Haven't used D6 in a long time. In trying to start D6, I now receive the following notice:

```
Your Just-in-Time Debugger is currently set to "C\ProgramData\verizon\debuggers\x86\cdb.exe" -pv -p %Id -c ".dump /u /m
C:\ProgramData\verizon\debuggers\crash_dumps\crash.dmp;.kill;qd"'. In order for Just-in-Time Debugging and Distributed Debugging features to work correctly, it needs to be changed to: "C:\D6\Bin\bordbg61.exe" -aeargs %Id %Id'. Do you want to change this setting?
```

When I answer "yes" to changing the setting, Delphi responds "Failed to set data for 'Debugger'". Then, Delphi 6 is minimized and won't respond.

My registry contains only 4 references to "C\ProgramData\verizon\debuggers\x86\cdb.exe"... . They are:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework]
"DbgManagedDebugger"="

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug]
"Debugger"=

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework]
"DbgManagedDebugger"=

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug]
"Debugger"=
```

I have absolutely no idea what to do now. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: did you try running D6 as an administrator? have a look at this http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.ide/200908/0908254700.html

Comment: Some help here perhaps, [How can I disable Delphi as just-in-time debugger?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6758741/576719).

Comment: It's been a long time since I had Delphi 6 installed so I cannot verify, but could you try starting it as Administrator? Perhaps it is failing to _set_ the debugger, because it needs elevation to do so. (Note: answer moved to comment.)

Comment: As all of the locations point to HKLM, and it requires administrative permissions to write to HKLM, my psychic debugging skills tell me that you were not running Delphi as an administrative user, and that the solution would be to run it (at least once) as an administrator so the key(s) could be updated.

Comment: Probably better for D6 not to be the JIT debugger and get D6 simply to stop checking that it is.

Comment: Running as administrator resolved my problem. However, I will also disable D6 as the just-in-time debugger. Thanks to all of you for your helpful comments. I guess I can't give credit as an answer to comments, but you were all correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try it to run as administrator and if you're in other version of windows;

set "C:\Delphi\Borland\Delphi6\Bin\delphi32.exe"

- properties\compatibility
  -compatibility mode
  as: Windows Xp service Pack 3

Set Configuration

- Run as administrator.

it should be work , at least for me it works.

I hope it helped you